# My app doesn't get the current location successfully

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I am a new in android programming .I want get curent user location and show near resturant for he/she.So I wrote the below code for get location on android studio.But It work unsuccessfully .Also I used a volley library in my project for get json information from wordpress. I do not know if the volley library interferes with the location or not.My code is :

```
  private  void  getlocationaddresss(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, new Locale("fa"));
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            stateName=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"لطفا لوکیشن خود را روشن نمایید",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    };


    configure_button();



}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            configure_button();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This method is for **cheack permissions** and call **requestLocationUpdates**.

```
void configure_button() {
    // first check for permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    ,10);
        }
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, listener);



}
```

How can I fixed it ?

Comment: is there anterior or so! please post your logcat! because code seems fine

Comment: you have to make sure that the GPS is enable in your device to get update user location.

Comment: @Rizwanatta does'nt have any error in logcat.just listener is empty

Comment: @Navin I sure its enable but  listener is empty

Comment: The way I see it! everything seems fine with your code! in which method you are trying to use this method getlocationaddresss() ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether **user has turned on location** to get current location.
Here is useful methods you can use directly in you app.

You can check like this in your activity. Where this refers to current activity context.

```
 if (!isLocationEnabled(this)){
                showLocationSettingsAlert(this);
                return;
            }
```

and

```
public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
    } else {
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }
}
```

and start location setting activity if not turned on

```
 public static void showLocationSettingsAlert(final Context mContext) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        //Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Enable GPS");
        //Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS permission allows us to access location. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.");
        //On Pressing Setting button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //On pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```